# xmlhttp->open does not open the php file

Tags: php, javascript, xmlhttprequest

My code below doesn't seem to be reaching the PHP file using the xmlhttp->open function. The function works with the field it's connected to, but once it gets to send, it doesn't activate the PHP file at all.

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
function showCity(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("top_banner_id").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 

  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {

    document.getElementById("top_banner_id").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("GET","townGrab.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

This is the error I'm getting in the Chrome console. I fixed the event handler error by changing the source file to the latest version of jQuery. However, there's an internal server error that remains to deal with:

```
Error in event handler for 'undefined': IndexSizeError: DOM Exception 1 Error: Index or size was negative, or greater than the allowed value.
    at P (chrome-extension://mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja/content_js_min.js:16:142)
    at null.<anonymous> (chrome-extension://mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja/content_js_min.js:18:417)
    at chrome-extension://mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja/content_js_min.js:1:182
    at miscellaneous_bindings:288:9
    at chrome.Event.dispatchToListener (event_bindings:390:21)
    at chrome.Event.dispatch_ (event_bindings:376:27)
    at chrome.Event.dispatch (event_bindings:396:17)
    at Object.chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnMessage (miscellaneous_bindings:254:22) event_bindings:380
GET website url here (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: The code seems fine to me. As a first step, you might want to inspect the network requests in your browsers developer console and see if your AJAX call reaches its destination.

Comment: Check with your browser's developer tools ([Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/)) under the Net/Network tab and check if the requests are being sent. If they are you can check the response code and update your question with that info.

Comment: Updated with error code.

Comment: What happens when trying to directly access the <website url here> address from the browser ?

Comment: Old fashioned error: "The website encountered an error while retrieving http://url/townGrab.php?q=Anguilla. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly."

Comment: Make sure to escape `str` when putting it in a URL.

Comment: Conclusion: Your JS code is (mostly) fine (except for the part where you would better escape `str` like Waleed Khan suggested, i.e. changing `+str` to `+encodeURIComponent(str)`). You need to find out why your PHP file is unreachable, but that is a server side issue (so if you need help there, some srrver-side code/info is required).